# Ordering triggers for Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a spreadsheet with 6 different scripts. I have been manually running these scripts in a certain order to get the desired output. I was wondering if it was possible to set up a weekly trigger where on Wednesday, the scripts would all run within a half hour of each other and in a particular order.

I looked at some of the documentation and I see that you can pick something like 4pm-5pm on Wednesdays, but Google does not guarantee when the trigger will actually occur and I see no mention of how to order triggers that fall within the same hour. I can't set up the triggers to be in 6 consecutive hours either, that is much too long to wait.

I also noticed some documentation for how to program in triggers and saw this code:

```
function triggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('fileHandling')
      .timeBased()
      .onWeekDay(ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY)
      .atHour(9)
      .create();
}
```

Is it possible to append an .atMinute(5), atMinute(10) etc to this code after the `.atHour` is set and then have my `triggers` function be triggered weekly to trigger the rest of the functions... or something like that? One last thing, I had to split up the code because of the amount of API calls.

Comment: Is it not possible to create another script that calls the other functions in the order you wish and then just connect that one to your trigger.

Comment: Would chaining the function calls time out the script, or does the time reset between each function? It would probably take more than 6 minutes to run them all back 2 back.

Comment: Can't you simply create a weekly trigger that calls the function that in turn creates triggers for other functions running close to each other?

Comment: I supposed you could run each function separately and have each one create a trigger for the next one.

Comment: I believe you could use a sidebar to call a javascript function that calls a google.script.run.function with a success handler which then calls another javascript function with a success handler and you can just keep it up until all of the functions have completed and the only limit is that any one of them cannot take longer than 6 minutes.